Beaver Multiplication Triples in Dynamic Indexing
Suppose that we have a series of operations, including matrix multiplication $(A × B)$ where $A$ and $B$ are matrices (will be result of other computations) inside our unsupervised machine learning algorithm.
As the matrices or my multiplication inputs' sizes are not clear in the beginning, how is it possible to declare Beaver Multiplication Triples ahead of time in an offline phase?
Further on, the dimensions of matrices are changing during computation. For instance, $A: m ×n$, it's dimensions can be converted to $m/2 × n/3$.
I appreciate any assistance.

What exactly do you mean by "the matrix sizes are not clear?" Are the matrix sizes related to the secret input ? If that's the case, then perhaps you have to iterate all the possible inputs and find an upper bound on the matrix size and prepare such a triple, because any other triple size will leak some information about the input.
If the matrix sizes are not related to the secret input, then you can always figure out the size and prepare the corresponding triples. Small matrix triples could ensemble larger matrix triples.

Thanks for your answer. Yes, matrix sizes are related to the secret input in the iterate. For instance, it can range from (2884, 17) to the lowest (10, 5) which will be defined during intermediate computations.

I'm afraid such kind of computation is unfriendly for practical MPC. You could either 1) reveal that size and define the size as part of the functionality output;  or 2) use  (2884, 17) what ever the intermediate values are.

It seems for me also not practical, unfortunately, with MPC at least based on my current understanding.
